# Check BIOS for hard drive

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I am running an Acer Aspire ... how do I check my BIOS to see if my hard drive is working? I say this because recently my computer gives me "Disk read error" and I want to see if my hardd drive still works. Thank you.

Comment: That's probably not only the way you would want to check whether a hard drive correctly works. Why not ask about the real problem you're facing and let those who answer figure out *where* to look? :) How exactly did you meet that error in the first place?

Comment: Slow computer. Tried turning it off. Froze on shutdown. Did a cold poweroff. Turned it on again. Windows load to blackscreen. Turned it off and on again...that error.

Comment: Can you give us system specs?

Comment: You'll have to enter the BIOS "Setup" program - press a keyboard key (could be *Esc*, *Del* or *F1*, depends on BIOS version) after a reset.  Depending on the BIOS version, it might display the detected drives on the main screen, or you may have to drill down a few menu selections.  There may be some configuration options, and if you're lucky, it can run a few S.M.A.R.T. tests on the HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to read the SMART data from your HDD to see whats wrong with it. [This link](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/perf/qual/featuresSMART-c.html) provides a good explanation on the SMART technology. If you have access to your OS, you can use many programs to read SMART data, like [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/hdtune.html).